# Failed to open database using geth

Tags: go-ethereum

Previously was able to do the setup successfully, today it didnt work.

```
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1$ **geth --datadir=./chaindata init genesis.json**

INFO [11-07|11:18:50] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1/chaindata/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
Fatal: Failed to open database: open /media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1/chaindata/geth/chaindata/LOCK: read-only file system.
```

Scanned various forum and the common reason stated was geth is already runing in the background, hence the error.

```
command: **lsof -i tcp:30303** didnt
```

gave any result. so no listening was happening on port 30303

Ran the command ps faux | grep geth, found the geth process that is active, killed it still the issue remains.

```
alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1$ **ps faux | grep geth**

alex      3506  0.0  0.0  14224   972 pts/8    S+   11:30   0:00          |       \_ grep --color=auto geth
alex      2839  2.5  1.8 1693852 74916 ?       Sl   11:07   0:35          |   \_ /home/alex/.config/Mist/swarmjs/bin/swarm --bzzaccount /home/alex/.config/Mist/swarmjs/swarmKey --datadir /home/alex/.config/Mist/swarmjs --ens-api /home/alex/.ethereum/geth.ipc

alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1$ k**ill -QUIT 3506**

bash: kill: (3506) - No such process

alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1$ **kill -QUIT 2839**

alex@alex-Inspiron-3558:/media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1$ **ps faux | grep geth**


alex      3512  0.0  0.0  14224   968 pts/8    S+   11:30   0:00          |       \_ grep --color=auto geth

alex      2839  2.5  1.9 1693852 75164 ?       Sl   11:07   0:35          |   \_ /home/alex/.config/Mist/swarmjs/bin/swarm --bzzaccount /home/alex/.config/Mist/swarmjs/swarmKey --datadir /home/alex/.config/Mist/swarmjs --ens-api /home/alex/.ethereum/geth.ipc.
```

let me know if you need further logs on this. Meanwhile I will try finding a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error:

```
Failed to open database: open /media/alex/Y/Blockchain/assignment_1/chaindata/geth/chaindata/LOCK: read-only file system.
```

I think you're using some type of external drive for the `--datadir=./chaindata` argument. I sure you're mounting that drive with the wrong permission.